# Excel-VBA: Pull data from multiple closed workbooks with filename starting with "xxx"

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make a macro that pulls data from multiple close workbooks into this (ThisWorkbook) workbook.

All the closed workbooks are in the same folder - but there are also files that it shouldt pull data from.

So only the files starting with "0101" in the filename.

I want to copy data from A1:D18 in the first sheet of the FIRST workbook and past it into ThisWorkbook cell A1 on active sheet. And for the rest I just want to copy the C3 and put it into a variable. And if there are multiple files then it should combine all the C3-values into the same variable.

Is that possible?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I haven't really tried much. I don't know the method to do it. I know how to copy and paste and so on. But loops/arrays are not something I know much about. Yet,

Comment: We won't code it for you, but we will help you when you are stuck at a certain point in your code. Search for some tutorials on this topic and try out the example code you find there. If you get stuck, update your question with the code in question, the current behaviour (error etc.), the desired behaviour and what you have tried so far to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This will open all Excel files starting with 0101:

```
Sub StringLoopOpen()

Dim folder As String
Dim file As String

folder = "C:\foo\bar"
file = Dir(folder & "\0101*.xlsx")

Do While file <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=folder & "\" & file
file = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

If you need to perform other tasks (such as moving the data, closing the files, etc.) do it in between "do while" and "loop".